# What is the probability of getting a specific reward in this scenario?

Tags: probability

There are $n$ players who each roll a reward from a table containing 6 items, each with their own probability of being chosen $r_i$, $i$ denoting which of the 6 items the probability belongs to. Each item has a value $V_i$ and when every player has rolled their reward, the item pulled with the greatest value is picked out from the rest and given to all players.

What is the probability $f_i$ of a given item being picked out in this way?

Also, if I wanted to calculate the average value obtained via this process, would that just be $\sum_{i=0}^6 f_i V_i$ ?

Comment: Are the items removed from the list once a player has won it?  If not, then the probability that  item $i$ is never selected in $(1-r_i)^n$, so you can get the probability that it is selected at least once by subtracting that from $1$.  The item of maximal value is sure to be awarded, so ignore that one.

Comment: Right, they aren't removed. Given what you wrote, if we set $g_i = (1-r_i)^n$, and say that some set $J_i$ contains all the items that have a higher value than item $i$, would the probability of $i$ being picked out at the end be $\left( 1-g_i \right)\prod_{j\in J_i}g_j$?

Comment: I don't understand.  The $g_i$ are clearly not independent, if that's what you are asking.  Knowing that item $i$ was never chosen makes it more likely that other elements were chosen.  So you won't get by with simple multiplication.

Comment: For instance, the probability that neither items $i$ nor $j$ (with $i\neq j$) were chosen is $(1-r_i-r_j)^n$, not $(1-r_i)^n(1-r_j)^n$.

Comment: You're right; given my misunderstanding and attempts on paper since, I don't have enough knowledge regarding statistics to come up with my own answer based on these hints